# Set permanently Current Page to print

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Microsoft word document - How to set print "current page only" for every time I print from that particular document.  I keep printing 100 pages instead of the one I want.

I know I can change each time, I just forget and wind up shutting printer down to quickly stop the printing, since canceling take a little longer.

Answer (score 2):

Do it with macro:

```
Sub PrintOne()
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut wdPrintCurrentPage
End Sub
```